# How to only select one radio button at a time in Python Tkinter?

Tags: python

I have been going through Tkinter examples and am now working with buttons.
When I select or deselect a button, all other buttons do the same thing.  How can I change it where only one button will change at a time?  I've tried other things but I'm not having any luck.

Here is my current code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk


class Adder(ttk.Frame):
    """The adders gui and functions."""
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.root = parent
        self.init_gui()

    def init_gui(self):
        """Builds GUI."""
        self.root.title('IDL  -  I.D. Lookup')

        self.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='nsew') # this starts the entire form

        self.num1_entry = ttk.Entry(self, width=15) # width of first input box
        self.num1_entry.grid(sticky='W', column=1, row = 2) # column and row it is placed on  # sticky='w' justifies or aligns to left

        self.num2_entry = ttk.Entry(self, width=10) # width of second input box
        self.num2_entry.grid(sticky='W', column=1, row=3) # column and row it is placed on

        self.calc_button = ttk.Button(self, text='Calculate') # button
        self.calc_button.grid(column=0, row=4, columnspan=4) # column and row it is placed on

        self.answer_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(self, text='Answer', height=100) # answer box
        self.answer_frame.grid(column=0, row=5, columnspan=4, sticky='nesw')

        self.rad_button = ttk.Radiobutton(self, text='Town').grid(sticky='W', column=0,row=6, columnspan=1)  # sticky W to align everything to left          
        self.rad_button = ttk.Radiobutton(self, text='Town1').grid(sticky='W', column=0,row=7, columnspan=1)
        self.rad_button = ttk.Radiobutton(self, text='Town2').grid(sticky='W', column=0,row=8, columnspan=1)
        self.rad_button = ttk.Radiobutton(self, text='Town3').grid(sticky='W', column=0,row=9, columnspan=1)
        self.rad_button = ttk.Radiobutton(self, text='Town4').grid(sticky='W', column=0,row=10, columnspan=1)
        self.rad_button = ttk.Radiobutton(self, text='Town5').grid(sticky='W', column=0,row=11, columnspan=1)
        self.rad_button = ttk.Radiobutton(self, text='Town6').grid(sticky='W', column=0,row=12, columnspan=1)
        self.rad_button = ttk.Radiobutton(self, text='Town7').grid(sticky='W', column=0,row=13, columnspan=1)
        self.rad_button = ttk.Radiobutton(self, text='Town8').grid(sticky='W', column=0,row=14, columnspan=1)

        self.answer_label = ttk.Label(self.answer_frame, text='') # text=' ' holds text in the answer box
        self.answer_label.grid(column=0, row=0)

        # Labels that remain constant throughout execution.
        ttk.Label(self, text='IDL - I.D. Lookup').grid(column=0, row=0,
                columnspan=4)
        ttk.Label(self, text='Name').grid(column=0, row=2,
                sticky='w')
        ttk.Label(self, text='I.D.').grid(column=0, row=3,
                sticky='w')

        ttk.Separator(self, orient='horizontal').grid(column=0, # line under title. 
                row=1, columnspan=4, sticky='ew')

        for child in self.winfo_children():
            child.grid_configure(padx=10, pady=4) # padx 10 adds horizontal padding on the out edge of window



if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    Adder(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tkinter radiobuttons require two options for proper operation that you're not providing: `variable` (a Tk variable to store the value of the selected button in the group, typically an IntVar or StringVar) and `value` (a distinct value for each button in the group, to be stored in the variable when that button is selected).  So you'd need:

```
self.selectedTown = tkinter.StringVar()
self.selectedTown.set('Town')
```

somewhere at the top, then things like:

```
ttk.Radiobutton(self, text='Town', value='Town', variable=self.selectedTown)
```

for each button; then something like

```
print self.selectedTown.get()
```

when you want to check which item was selected.

PS:  Assigning all of your buttons to the same variable `self.rad_button` is kind of pointless.  You're not assigning the actual button itself, anyway: you're assigning None each time, which is the result of the `.grid()` call on each line.